# How to use Future<AudioCache>?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

Question by a Flutter Newbie ;D :

I want to play an audiofile and be able to set its volume or pause it.

The function "loop" returns a variable of the type Future but the documentation (https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md) says it returns type AudioPlayer.

```
Future<AudioPlayer> audioPlayer = audioCache.loop('background_music.mp3');
```

should be

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = audioCache.loop('background_music.mp3');
```

But how can I work with this variable or convert it to AudioPlayer?

```
AudioPlayer.pause();
```

works but not
    Future.pause();

My Solution:

```
    Future<AudioPlayer> audioPlayer = audioCache.loop('background_music.mp3');
  audioPlayer.then((player) {
    player.setVolume(0.2);
  });
```

Comment: see [loop](https://pub.dev/documentation/audioplayers/latest/audio_cache/AudioCache/loop.html) method documentation - it returns `Future<AudioPlayer>` - now read official `Future` documentation on how to get `AudioPlayer` object from that `Future`

Comment: @pskink Thanks, it worked. I posted my code that I am using now at the top.

Comment: good, that's how `Future`s work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concept**

`Future`s in Dart is something similar to `Promise` in JS world. Futures indicate that something is going to happen at some point in the future. The best part about it is that it allows Dart not to block program execution until a computation is done. It allows Dart to keep running other parts of your application that do not depend on that usually slow computation. Such as starting to loop an audio file.

To loop an audio file you have to do a bunch of things:

1. load the file from FS into memory
2. instantiate an AudioPlayer
3. set some properties on it

Out of all that, reading the file-system is a relatively slow operation, therefore wrapped in a Future. [Read more about futures here](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures)

> But how can I work with this variable or convert it to AudioPlayer?

1. `await` the future: `AudioPlayer loopingPlayer = await audioCache.loop('somefile');`
2. `then` the future: `audioCache.loop('somefile').then((pl) { /* do work here */ });`

> works but not Future.pause();

That is because `Future` (a class), doesn't have a method `pause()`. `AudioPlayer` does. So to call that method, you have to wait for the computation wrapped in a Future to complete (in this case, the things I mentioned above).